# Отправка 2x изображений в multipart/form-data с помощью Retrofit

Tags: java, android, html, изображения, retrofit

Я делаю программу на *Android* работающее с изображениями. Мне нужно отправить **2 Bitmap** изображения в **multipart/form-data**.

**Multipart/form-data**:

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple="" name="file[]" class="span3"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="span2">
</form>
```

Проблема в том что я не знаю как отправить в *multipart/form-data* *2 Bitmap* изображения. *Для удобства 2 Bitmap изображения хранятся в отдельном классе, как 2 static переменные (photoOne, photoTwo)*. Помогите решить мою проблему.

Comment: Зачем вам какие-то формы и html? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562950/post-multipart-form-data-using-retrofit-2-0-including-image

Comment: Отправка должна производится в определенную папку в мой Rest API. В form закидываются два изображения, как только это происходит, перекидывает на "http:/...com/photoOne/photoTwo", изображения берутся из папки и они обединияются, выводится полученное изображение, которое должно загрузится на устройстве.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрите вариант на стороне javascript - закодировать контент файлов в base64, и передать на сервер просто две строки.

На стороне сервера вы преобразуете строки в byte array и выполняете необходимую вам обработку.

Comment: Rest API написан на Python(Flask), попробую сделать как вы сказали